# Odoo 9 Javascript call function of other widget

Tags: javascript, odoo-9

I need to call funcion of "FilterMenu" widged from "FavoriteMenu" widget that I extending. 
There is standard Odoo widget:

```
odoo.define('web.FilterMenu', function (require) {
  "use strict";

  var data_manager = require('web.data_manager');
  var search_filters = require('web.search_filters');
  var search_inputs = require('web.search_inputs');
  var Widget = require('web.Widget');

  return Widget.extend({
  ...
```

And another one that i extending:

```
odoo.define("favorite_editor.favorite", function (require) {
  "use strict";
  var FavoriteMenu = require('web.FavoriteMenu');
  var FilterMenu = require('web.FilterMenu');
  ...
  FavoriteMenu.include({
  ...
  edit_filter: function (filter, $filter, key) {
    var self = this;
    var filter_menu = new FilterMenu();
    fields = filter_menu.get_fields();
```

Function `edit_filter` called by pressing some button and its works fine.
Last row is wrong because in `get_fields` function `this` contains `FavoriteMenu` and not `FilterMenu` instance, but I need the `FilterMenu` instance.
Moreover I need the `FilterMenu` instance that already exists so as to use existing data.

Can someone suggest how to deal with it ?

Comment: if you do `new FilterMenu()`, you'll get a new instance. What you want is to inject an existing instance to your `FavoriteMenu`. If you can't do that easily with Odoo, try to make an indirection, i.e. create a new object that will retain references to existing `FilterMenu` or `FavoriteMenu` (make it a singleton too) ; then request this globally available singleton for specific `FilterMenu` or `FavoriteMenu`.